# Using cypress with django in Gitlab CI

Tags: django, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cypress

I am developing an application using *Django* and I use *Cypress* for front-end testing. The setup works locally, but I would like to set-up the testing on *gitlab-ci*.

I have managed to make Gitlab run Cypress tests (while the application runs on production server). What I'd like to achieve (and I am struggling to) is to have Gitlab CI running Django application (probably even with nginx/gunicorn, mimicking the production environment; but embedded dev. server would suffice, too).

**Is it even possible? To run the server and have Cypress running in the one go?**
I've seen some examples using docker-compose on Gitlab-CI for nodejs applications - but I'd like to avoid it as setting it all together correctly (so that it uses cache etc.) seems to be super troublesome task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to do it in pure bash. By `&` operator you can run 2 task in parallel.

`python manage.py runserver & npx cypress run` will run django and cypress and result of last one (cypress) will be final result of command.

If you backend need some time to run i suggest to run cypress after some time (e.g. 5s) by `python manage.py runserver & (sleep 5 && npx cypress run)`

And if you want to kill backend process you can save `pid` of this process into file by `python manage.py runserver & echo $! > backend.pid & npx cypress run` and run `kill $(cat backend.pid)` command to kill process with id saved in this file

Comment: The trick with pidfile and killing after cypress exits seems the most suitable.
There is one more question though - which docker base image to use? Python should base upon `python:3`, while cypress runs on `cypress/base:10`; would using `cypress/base:10` and installing python3 inside be good enough?

Comment: In my opinion there will be nothing wrong with creating docker container with cypress and python3 for ci purpose.